# How to read MVC OWIN AuthenticationProperties?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, owin

I'm setting IsPersistent when signing the user in, how to read that value back?

```
var identity = await UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(appUser, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = false }, identity);
```

Comment: @MarioDS, there is a reason this question has not received attention. Being that it is not very clear. But putting that aside you should first understand what the property is about. check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/32052308/5233410 In short it (the property) is not stored to be read back. It just instructs the framework to create a cookie. So my assumption is that once the cookie is present then the property was probably set to true, and would be otherwise false.

Comment: @Nkosi I realized that soon after I set the bounty - no turning back unfortunately :). What I actually wanted to know is how to read other properties back (especially the ones set in the "Dictionary" of AuthenticationProperties).

Comment: maybe this link will help you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31946582/how-ispersistent-works-in-owin-cookie-authentication

Comment: @nik which authentication u use??

Comment: Could you explain more details about where you want to read authentication props in view, other controller, etc??

Answer (score 1):

`AspNet.Identity` gives you access to the `bool` value of `IsPersistent` for the session. The most direct way to read its value is to call `AuthenticateAsync()`:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
var authenticateResult = await HttpContext.GetOwinContext()
                           .Authentication.AuthenticateAsync(
                               DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie
                           );
var isPersistent = authenticateResult.Properties.IsPersistent; //// true or false
```

Note that you will need to wrap this in an `async` method, such as:

```
@using System.Threading.Tasks;
public async Task<ActionResult> SomeMethodName(...) { //etc }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there isn't much description, I am not sure about the context. Anyway, you can get all the `AuthenticationProperties` that were provided with the sign in call when you perform authentication on the current request. Code would be..

```
AuthenticateResult authenticateResult = await HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.AuthenticateAsync(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

AuthenticationProperties yourAuthenticationProperties = authenticateResult.Properties;
```

Answer (score 0):

can you please try this, I haven't test it

```
IAuthenticationManager AuthenticationManager
{
  get { return HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication; }
}
```

Comment: ... and then ...?

Answer (score 0):

As @Nkosi said you can **not** retrieve the information from the OWIN, because it's not stored there, you need to retrieve the cookie itself and parse the information manually, but for that you will need a OWIN Middleware like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43167114/1529884) so you can manipulate your cookie as you want.

Comment: I think this statement is incorrect. `IsPersistent` actually exists within `HttpContext.GetOwinContext`.

Comment: Could you please point exactly where one could find isPersistent in HttpContext.GetOwinContext?

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a `static property CookieAuthOptions` if you configured `CookieAuthOptions` in ConfigureAuth or any other AuthOption should also implement  `ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket>`(eg: `OAuthBearerOptions.AccessTokenFormat`). This one contains `Protect` & `Unprotect` methods.

Whenever you need to access `AuthenticationProperties`, you have to be able to get a grip of Owin context to get a reference to a ticket that implements your correct format.

As a basic example steps,

```
Startup.cs => public static CookieAuthenticationOptions  CookieAuthOptions; 
Startup.cs => ConfigureAuth => CookieAuthOptions.CookieName = "xxx"; 
BaseController.cs => Startup.CookieAuthOptions.TicketDataFormat.Unprotect(Request.Cookies["xxx"].Value).Properties;
```

to get what you want.

PS: You did not mention where you need this and I assumed it would be in a  controller.

Answer (score 0):

```
AuthenticateResult authenticateResult = await HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.AuthenticateAsync(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

AuthenticationProperties yourAuthenticationProperties = authenticateResult.Properties;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var authenticationInfo = await HttpContext.Authentication.GetAuthenticateInfoAsync(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
authenticationInfo.Properties ...
```

I asume *DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie* contains cookie authentication scheme.