# How to get isPersistent (AuthenticationProperties)

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm using asp.net MVC 5.2 with asp.net identity version 2.2.1 and Entity Framework 6.1.3.
At some point, in a controller, I need to know the contents of AuthenticationProperties currently being used, more specifically I need to know the value of isPersistent.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read MVC OWIN AuthenticationProperties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24900113/how-to-read-mvc-owin-authenticationproperties)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

May be this can help:

```
var isPersistent  = ((System.Web.Security.FormsIdentity) User.Identity).Ticket.IsPersistent;
```

Or

```
   FormsIdentity id = (FormsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;
   FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = id.Ticket;

   var isPersistent = ticket.IsPersistent.ToString();
```

Comment: Hi Neel,
I've tried that and I get this error:
System.InvalidCastException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2147467262
  Message=Unable to cast object of type 'System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity' to type 'System.Web.Security.FormsIdentity'.

Comment: authCookie  returns null,  I'm using identity, not forms authentication.

Comment: Hey there are so many sites which shows this code: https://snipt.net/raw/748b51b939b9db3bba66c74c05baebc7/?nice and http://www.martinwilley.com/net/asp/security/forms.html

Answer (score 2):

The contents of `AuthenticationProperties` for the current session are accessible to you via `AspNet.Identity` by calling `AuthenticateAsync()`. Form authentication here is not relevant because the session falls under `Identity`.

To get the entire `AuthenticationProperties` object:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
@using System.Threading.Tasks;
public async Task<ActionResult> SomeMethodName(...) {
{    
    var authenticateResult = await HttpContext.GetOwinContext()
                       .Authentication.AuthenticateAsync(
                           DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie
                       );
```

One you have `authenticateResult`, the syntax for extracting property values ( in your case `IsPersistent`) is:

```
var isPersistent = authenticateResult.Properties.IsPersistent; //// true or false
```