# Asp.Net Core 6 : Get the value of IsPersistent in the controller at .net 6 mvc?

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, claims

I used remember me in the form,Now I want to get the value of IsPersistent and put a code condition on one of the actions.
I searched a lot but couldn't find anything, even the links below didn't help.

[How to get is session IsPersistent on ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40341591/how-to-get-is-session-ispersistent-on-asp-net-mvc)

[How to get isPersistent (AuthenticationProperties)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38563807/how-to-get-ispersistent-authenticationproperties)

Claims Code :

```
private void LoginByClaims(Guid userid, Guid roleid,bool remembr)
{
    var claims = new List<Claim>()
                {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name,userid.ToString()),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier,roleid.ToString()),
                };
    var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
    var properties = new AuthenticationProperties
    {
        IsPersistent = remembr
    };

    HttpContext.SignInAsync(principal, properties);

}
```

Action for condition :

```
 public IActionResult Login()
{
    
    if (User.Identity.Name == null)
    {
        return View();
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Dashboard", "Profile");
}
```

If the remember me check was done, will it go to one action, and if it was not checked, to another action?